# How do I edit data before passing it $scope?

Tags: json, angularjs, service, controller, scope

I have an issue with this controller.

consumer service and when I get the data "data" show them on a list and everything works fine.

---

```
.controller('AccountsCtrl', function($scope, getAccountsData){
        getAccountsData.resp.query(function(data){

        $scope.accounts = data;

        },function(dataError){

        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Login failed!',
                        template: 'Please check your credentials!' + JSON.stringify(dataError)
        });
    });
    })
```

---

but But when I want to edit the "data" before passing to "$scope" I can not see anything on the list.

---

```
.controller('AccountsCtrl', function($scope, getAccountsDataServices){
        getAccountsDataServices.resp.query(function(data){

             for(var i in data){

            if(data[i].account.type.id == '17'){
                data[i].status.formattedReservedAmount = "texto editado";
                 };
            };

        $scope.accounts = data;

        },function(dataError){

        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Error!',
            template: 'Please check!
        });
    });
    })
```

---

---------------View------------------

```
            <div class="name">{{ account.account.type.name }}</div>
            <div class="diner">{{ account.status.formattedReservedAmount }}</div>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

---

Received data is:

```
[{"account": {
            "id": 913,
            "type": {
                "id": 17,
                "name": "account-1"
            },
            "default": true
        },
        "status": {
            "formattedReservedAmount": "$ 0,00 Pesos"
        }
    },
    {
        "account": {
            "id": 4050,
            "type": {
                "id": 35,
                "name": "account-2"
            },
            "default": false
        },
       "status": {
            "formattedReservedAmount": "$ 0,00 Pesos"
        }}]
```

Comment: Are you sure data is an object? If it is a string, try doing data = JSON.parse(data) before iterating it.

Comment: The type.id is an int, not a string right? Should it not be: if(data[i].account.type.id === 17)? Is the issue that the data isnt changed? Or its lost completely?

Comment: @OliverMcPhee It will work just fine. Data type doesn't matter in this case. It's much safer to use `==`. @cmauroie your code seems working properly. I tested it and it's working fine.

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. Ok, I've been prodded to use === to save in type conversion. Just as a performance point really, though I only have anecdotal evidence of this. As you pointed out though - its not causing the issue here.

Comment: this error after iterate and want to see the results of data to "scope" can not see the list. @ Alberto I.N.J. ** <ion-list class=""> <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/categories" collection- repeat="account in accounts"> <div class="name">{{ account.account.type.name }}</div> </ion-item> </ion-list>**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.controller('AccountsCtrl', function(`$scope`, getAccountsDataServices){
getAccountsDataServices.resp.query(function(data){   
`$scope.accounts` = data.map(function (c) {      
          if (c.account.type.id == '17'){
             c.status.formattedReservedAmount = ':DDDD';
          }
           return c;
    });
    }, function(error) {
    $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Error!',
            template: 'Please Check!'
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A forEach on the results should do the trick.

```
.controller('AccountsCtrl', function($scope, getAccountsDataServices){
    getAccountsDataServices.resp.query(function(data){
        angular.forEach(data, function(a) {
            if (a.account.type.id === 17) {
                a.account.status.formattedReservedAmount = 'texto editado';
            }
        });

        $scope.accounts = data;
    }, function(error) {
        $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Error!',
            template: 'Please Check!'
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried your code but not work for me. because I need in: $ scope.accounts = data; // After editing

Comment: You're correct. I edited the answer. Otherwise, was this answer correct?

Comment: //The data can not be seen in view.  '<ion-list class="">
              <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/categories" collection-repeat="account in accounts">
            
                <div class="name">{{ account.account.type.name }}</div>
                <div class="diner">{{ account.status.formattedReservedAmount }}</div>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-list>'